# Tensor/Vector decomposition/representation & DOF argument

Tags: general-relativity, potential, tensor-calculus, degrees-of-freedom

In fluid mechanics, for irrotational flow it is sometimes useful to present the velocity, $U$ in terms of a scalar potential $\Phi$ as:

$$\vec{U}=\nabla \phi$$

$\vec{U}$ has 3 dof. $\phi$ has 1.

Why does this work, in terms of a dof arguement?

e.g . compared to GR common decomposition of the Riemann tensor into

$$R^{\nu\lambda\kappa\rho} =R*^{\nu\lambda\kappa\rho} + BR\eta*^{\nu\lambda\kappa\rho} + C^{\nu\lambda\kappa\rho},$$ (1)

With $C^{\nu\lambda\kappa\rho}$ is traceless, $$R=\eta_{\nu\kappa} \eta_{\lambda\rho}R^{\nu\lambda\kappa\rho}$$, where $\eta^{ab}$ denotes the Minkowski metric and $B,C$ are constants, and where $R*^{\nu\lambda\kappa\rho}$ denotes $$R*^{\nu\lambda\kappa\rho}=\frac{1}{4}\left[{R}^{\nu\kappa}\eta^{\lambda\rho}-R^{\nu\rho}\eta^{\lambda\kappa}+{R}^{\lambda\rho}\eta^{\nu\kappa}-{R}^{\lambda\kappa}\eta^{\nu\rho}\right] $$ and

$$ \eta*^{\nu\lambda\kappa\rho}= 2\eta^{\nu\kappa}\eta^{\lambda\rho}-2\eta^{\nu\rho}\eta^{\lambda\kappa} $$

From what I understand the tensors making up the decomposition can be a number of degrees of freedom at most the same as the object they are making up, and altogether they must have at least the total number of dof of the object they are making up. So , e.g. if T=A+B+C, and T has 10 d.o.f, then each of A,B,C can have any number between [1,10] of d.o.f, and altogether they must have at least 10 d.o.f? Is this correct?

(Note by d.o.f I mean number of independent arguments).